# Image formats NV12 storage in memory

Tags: image-processing, yuv, image-formats, nv12-nv21

I am totally understand about the size of the NV12 format as described in question

[NV12 format and UV plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487048/nv12-format-and-uv-plane)

Now I am reading from two sources about the storage of UV plane in this format:
one is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750(v=vs.85).aspx

**NV12**

All of the Y samples appear first in memory as an array of unsigned char values with an even number of lines. The Y plane is followed immediately by an array of unsigned char values that contains packed U (Cb) and V (Cr) samples. When the combined U-V array is addressed as an array of little-endian WORD values, the LSBs contain the U values, and the MSBs contain the V values. NV12 is the preferred 4:2:0 pixel format for DirectX VA. It is expected to be an intermediate-term requirement for DirectX VA accelerators supporting 4:2:0 video. The following illustration shows the Y plane and the array that contains packed U and V samples.

What I understand is: in UV plane **each U and V are stored in single byte**.

When I read from wikipedia about this:
https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV#NV12

It says:

**NV12**

Related to I420, NV12 has one luma "luminance" plane Y and one plane with U and V values interleaved.
In NV12, chroma planes (blue and red) are subsampled in both the horizontal and vertical dimensions by a factor of 2.
For a 2x2 group of pixels, you have 4 Y samples and 1 U and 1 V sample.
It can be helpful to think of NV12 as I420 with the U and V planes interleaved.
Here is a graphical representation of NV12. Each letter represents one bit:
For 1 NV12 pixel: YYYYYYYY UVUV
For a 2-pixel NV12 frame: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY UVUVUVUV
For a 50-pixel NV12 frame: Y*8*50 (UV)*2*50
For a n-pixel NV12 frame: Y*8*n (UV)*2*n

What I understand here is : **each U and V are interleaved bit by bit in each byte. So each each byte of UV plane will contain 4U bits and 4V bits interleaved.**

Can anyone clarify my doubt?

Comment: There is no bit interleaving, (only) **bytes** interleaving.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## TL;DR: MSDN is correct

To verify this (or at least verify that there is no interleaving on bit level), one can use `ffmpeg`, which is a widely used video tool. I did the following experiment:

1. Make a file containing some text (I took the example Lorem Ipsum text)
2. Tell `ffmpeg` to read it as a `I420` video frame of some small size
3. Tell `ffmpeg` to convert it to `NV12` format
4. Print it

Here is an example commandline for (2) and (3):

```
ffmpeg -s 96x4 -i example_i420.yuv -pix_fmt nv12 example_nv12.yuv
```

Here is what I got in the output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, s**utnett uirn
>   acduilppias cqiunig  oeflfiitc,i as edde sdeor uenitu smmooldl itte
>   mapnoirm  iindc iedsitd ulnatb ourtu ml.a bLoorree me ti pdsoulmo rdeo
>   lmoarg nsai ta laimqeuta,. cUotn seenci**

I marked the chroma (U and V) samples in bold. It is evident that these are the same values (ASCII letters), just in scrambled order. If any bit-interleaving were performed, I would get different values.

So the description in the VLC wiki (BTW it's **not** Wikipedia) is incorrect. Someone with the name "Edwardw" added the "illustration" mentioning pixels [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/index.php?title=YUV&diff=23649&oldid=23648), and later changed it to "bits" [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/index.php?title=YUV&diff=23650&oldid=23649). I hope someone changes it to be less misleading (the wiki requires registration so I cannot edit it).